# Loading json translation files in a standalone vue2 spa

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a single page app index.html and i want to translate using json files in the same folder as the index.html file. The json files are inside the locales directory. I put them there to enable automation in translating. My code looks like this

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
console.log('base url', window.location.origin)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'de',
  messages:loadLocaleMessages()
});

const vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n:i18n,
  data: { 
   display: 'data...' 
  },

  mounted () {
   console.log('store accessed', this.display)
  },
  
  methods: {
   change_language: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected_language = event.target.value
    this.$i18n.locale = selected_language
    }
}
})
```

The problem is using `require.context` inside the browser although using require from cdn `<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>`

Since require is available on webpack, does fetching require from cdn exempt us from using browsersify?

My locale en.json looks like this

```
{
"app_title": "Vendor Section Section",
"login": "Login",
"register": "Register",
"forgot_password": "Forgot Password",
"login_with_google": "Login With",
"register_with_google": "Register With",
"email": "Email",
"password": "Password",
"confirm_password": "Confirm Password",
"vendor_forgot_password": "Vendor Forgot Password",
"vendor_registration": "Vendor Registration",
"vendor_login": "Vendor Login"
}
```

How can i load the locales and be able to use the locale file in my spa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the way you initialize Vue-i18n. Instead of providing all the locales at boot - you will now init only the default locale (probably English). When you want to change to another locale - you will first check whether `this.$root.$i18n.messages[localeCode]` is undefined. If it is - then you will fetch the locale from your public folder and add it to the `this.$root.$i18n.messages` object and then switch to the new locale. In case you already have fetched the locale - no need to refetch it again.

Comment: How do i load the json from file, thats the tricky part  Even `<script type="module">
   import require from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/require';
 </script>` doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Gandalf You will have to use good old XHR/fetch.

Comment: @MichalLevý I switched to jquery and made it work.